# AWS CloudFormation outputs to JenkinsFile pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cloudformation

I have cloudFormation.yaml and JenkinsFile.groovy.
In cloudFormation has outputs:

```
Outputs:
  bucketName:
    Value: !Ref BucketName
    Description: 'bucket name'
```

I run cloudFormation:

```
stage("run cloudFormation") {
            steps {
                script {
                    withAWS(credentials: awsCredentials) {
                        cfnUpdate(
                            stack: stackName,
                            file: "cloudFormation.yaml",
                            params: [
                                "uniqString=${uniqString}"
                            ],
                            timeoutInMinutes: 10,
                            pollInterval: 600
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I get outputs backetName in my JenkinsFile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just assign it to a var

```
def outputs = cfnUpdate(...)
```

see the link below for further information: 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin/blob/master/README.md